# perl smokeping false packet loss

Tags: ping, perl, network-monitoring

I'm getting false packet loss from time to time. The period lasts about month, you can see it on graph. We checked it using the same fping command and got no loss at all. So maybe were are hosts limit or something which can not handle it? But why it fixes itself after some period?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: image graph]

Comment: Problem soved: The main reason was that some hosts pinged through Cisco switch, which has rules for those packets.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it, so it is marked as "solved" in the system. Otherwise it will regularly pop up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem soved: The main reason was that some hosts pinged through Cisco switch, which has rules for those packets